# How do I start Firefox without restoring tabs?

Tags: firefox

I usually close Firefox with the command:

`killall firefox`

Many websites and tabs accumulate over time. At the end of the day, many remain unprocessed and should not be processed the next day either.

So I want to close Firefox and start it again as empty as possible, but Firefox restores all tabs.

How could I prevent this?

**Update**

Using firefox 99.0

Comment: This is a "I'm not using it how I'm supposed to and it's not working how it's supposed to" kind of question.

Comment: You could do it from the GUI by opening the profile manager (use switch `-profilemanager` IIRC), then create a new profile and launch.

Comment: This feels like an XY(?) problem. Why would you use `killall firefox` when `Alt`+`F4` exists, or `Ctrl`+`Q`, or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`W`, or clicking the close button, all of which gracefully close Firefox faster, and without causing your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tab recovery data is stored in the `sessionstore-backups` directory under your profile directory (example `~/.mozilla/firefox/..XYZ..x.default-release/sessionstore-backups/` ) . If you delete (or move to a different location in case you change your mind or something breaks) all the files in this directory there will be nothing to restore. You can for example make a wrapper script to clean-invoke firefox that wipes this directory first.

Comment: how i could find it? i also don't find it here: `~/.mozilla/firefox/`

Comment: i found such a folder now here: `/.mozilla/firefox/..XYZ..x.default-release/sessionstore-backups/`

Comment: @SL5net: Yes, the profile directories (whether you have one or more than one) are semi-randomly named directories under `~/.mozilla/firefox`.

Answer (score 8):

Killall firefox will force firefox to restore its tabs, no matter what your settings are.
Most convenient way is to open Settings->General and untick "Open previous windows and tabs":

[image]

If you want to prevent event the restore on a crash (which you are doing by "kill") you could setup in about:config

```
browser.sessionstore.resume_session_once True
```

In case it is not there, you could add it by entering it into `about:config`, select "boolean" ,then pressing the "+" button

Comment: this entry `about:config`> `browser.sessionstore.resume_session_once True` is not in this new firefox verson (99.0). i tried `browser.startup.couldRestoreSession.count` = 0 but it automatically set it to 1. and all pages are restored later in my test

Comment: That is an important info. I added it into your question

Comment: in FF v105.0 i set `browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand` `false`. now FF asks me to restore next before restore

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > General > Startup
and then uncheck the option "Open previous windows and tabs"

Comment: yes there is this option. but it is already unchecked. hmm https://i.imgur.com/Cm7AxlM.png

Comment: This option only applies to a normal start. But the OP is deliberately crashing Firefox instead of shutting it down, and Firefox will then try to recover from the crash into the exact same state right before it crashed, no matter what the this option is set to. In fact, before this setting existed, deliberately crashing Firefox was the *only way* to get it to restore tabs, and thus this trick was used by many users.